# Persistent Audio Player

Tags: 7

Is there a way to have a persistent audio player between page navigations? HOw do you prevent the player from restarting on a page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of challenges to overcome but it's doable. My sandbox project makes a persistent player possible in Drupal 7. Check it out: [Ajax pages](http://drupal.org/sandbox/jamix/1988012).

Comment: Looks interesting, I will definitely check it out, I like the Demos so far

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do that is to actually NOT refresh the page each time but rather use ajax or something similar to refresh only certain areas of the page while leaving the player area intact.

An example of this is pitchfork.com.  It has a player in the upper right gutter.  When you click on a link, what happens is the main content area of the page is reloaded but the page stays the same, so the player keeps on playing.

But, if you hit the reload button on your browser, it stops and starts all over again because the page itself was reloaded.

Of course, you could always put the player in a pop-up/under window and then you wouldn't have to worry about it as much.

Answer (score 0):

The post about [Render only the contents of page.tpl programatically?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1625124) gave some insight on how to do it, using the [Ajax Regions](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_regions) module. Here is an excerpt from the module's project page:

> ... allows to configure flexibly the internal links of your site, which will update the appointed regions using Ajax, instead of full page refresh.